# Fourier transform is uniformly continuous

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am trying to prove the following statement:

If $f \in L^1$, then $\hat f$ is uniformly continuous.

The argument given is as follows :

$$|\hat f (\xi +h )-\hat f (\xi)| = \left| \int f(x) (e^{-2 \pi i x \cdot (\xi+h)}- e^{-2 \pi i x \cdot (\xi)})\mathrm dx \right| \leq 2 \|f\|_{L^1}$$

Now I suppose we have to use the Dominated Convergence Theorem, but I am unable to see to what sequence of functions we apply the theorem to.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried approximating $f$ by a compactly supported smooth (or continuous) function, that is, take $\varphi\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathrm{R}^n)$ with $||f-\varphi||_{L^1}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ or something alike? I think you could make the argument work this way...

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But could you please elaborate a little bit more. Why do we need to approximate it by a compactly supported continuous function?

Comment: I haven't done the calculation, but it's a very common trick, and it might work here. You'll have $$ | \hat{f}(a+h)-\hat{f}(a) | \leq 2 ||f-\varphi||_{L^1} + | \int \varphi(x)(e^{2i\pi x\cdot (a+h)}-e^{2i\pi x\cdot a})dx|$$ in other words, $$|\hat{f}(a+h)-\hat{f}(a)|\leq 2||f-\varphi||_{L^1}+ |\hat{\varphi}(a+h)-\hat{\varphi}(a)|$$ and you only have to show the property for smooth compactly supported functions. Finally, you can say something like $$|\hat{\varphi}(a+h)-\hat{\varphi}(a)|\leq\int_{|x|\leq R}||\varphi||_{L^{\infty}}|e^{2i\pi x\cdot h}-1|dx$$ and I think that should almost do it.

Comment: Alternatively, you can remember the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma, that tells you that $\hat{f}$ is continuous and tends to $0$ as $|x|$ tends to $\infty$, and such functions are always uniformly continuous (easy exercise).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind explanations.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21710/uniform-continuity-question

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I don't know if your questions has been answered in full.  For completeness, we apply DCT for the reasons you mentioned in your post.  The punchline of the story is:

$$\begin{align}
\left|\widehat{f}(\xi + h) - \widehat{f}(\xi)\right|  &=  \left| \int f(x) \left(e^{-2 \pi i x \cdot (\xi + h)} - e^{-2 \pi i \xi \cdot x} \right)dx \right|
\\
&\leq \int |f(x)| \left|e^{2 \pi i x \cdot h} - 1  \right| dx
\end{align}$$

which tends to zero as $h \to 0$, and this is enough to show uniform continuity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Should we separate the integral domain by two parts like what @robjohn did? One is a neighborhood of the origin, and the other one is the rest of whole space.

Answer (score 24):

I like Olivier's comment suggesting the use of the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma, but here is a different approach.
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{f}(\xi+\eta)-\hat{f}(\xi)
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)\left(e^{-2\pi ix\cdot(\xi+\eta)}-e^{-2\pi ix\cdot\xi}\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)\left(e^{-2\pi ix\cdot\eta}-1\right)e^{-2\pi ix\cdot\xi}\;\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
For any $f\in L^1$ and $\epsilon>0$, by Dominated Convergence, we can find an $R>0$ so that
$$
\int_{|x|>R}|f(x)|\mathrm{d}x<\frac{\epsilon}{4}\tag{2}
$$
Let $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{4\pi R\|f\|_{L^1}}$. For $|x|\le R$ and $|\eta|<\delta$,
$$
\left|e^{-2\pi ix\cdot\eta}-1\right|\le\frac{\epsilon}{2\|f\|_{L^1}}\tag{3}
$$
whereas for all $x$,
$$
\left|e^{-2\pi ix\cdot\eta}-1\right|\le2\tag{4}
$$
Then, for $|\eta|<\delta$,
$$
\begin{align}
|\hat{f}(\xi+\eta)-\hat{f}(\xi)|
&\le\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f(x)|\;|e^{-2\pi ix\cdot\eta}-1|\;\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{|x|<R}|f(x)|\;|e^{-2\pi ix\cdot\eta}-1|\;\mathrm{d}x
+\int_{|x|\ge R}|f(x)|\;|e^{-2\pi ix\cdot\eta}-1|\;\mathrm{d}x\\
&\le\|f\|_{L^1}\frac{\epsilon}{2\|f\|_{L^1}}+\;2\frac{\epsilon}{4}\\
&=\epsilon
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing the details.

Comment: How do we justify that for all $|x| \leq R$, we have $\left| e^{-2\pi i x. \eta}-1 \right| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2\|f\|_{L^1}}$?

Comment: @pikachuchameleon: by our choice of $\delta$ and the fact that $2\pi| x||\eta|\le\frac{\epsilon}{2\|f\|_{L^1}}$

Comment: @robjohn, I'm not sure how you can conclude what pikachuchameleon said from that.  Don't you need a smaller $\delta$ for that bound?

Comment: @SeñorBilly: No. We're considering bound $(3)$, which follows since $\left|e^{ix}-1\right|\le|x|$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't know that happened, but it makes sense. I'll try to prove it.

Comment: @GuillermoMosse Just use the Taylor expansion of $e^{ix}$ and the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 0):

**I)** The proof for $L_1$ is simpler actually; here is an **outline**:

1) Prove that a linear map $f : E\to E'$ is continuous (even uniformly) iff it is continuous at *zero* (0); i.e.

$$\begin{align}
(\exists c\ \epsilon \ \mathbb{R}) \ |f(x)|\leq c|x|
\end{align}$$

2) Fourier transform is a *linear functional* defined on $L_1$. So, by (1) you only need to prove it is continuous at 0:
We have:

$$\begin{align}
F(f) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)e^{-j\omega x}dx
\end{align}$$
Where F is the Fourier operator defined on L1.
$$\begin{align}
|F(f)| = \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)e^{-j\omega x}dx\right| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)e^{-j\omega x}|dx \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)|dx = \left \| f \right \|_{L^1} < {\infty}
\end{align}$$
Thus 
$$\begin{align}
\left | F(f) \right | \leq 1 \left \| f \right \|_{L^1},
\end{align}$$
This completes the proof (set c = 1)

**II)** Yes, you could use DCT, here's how:
Take any sequence $$x_n \to 0$$
Set $$ u_n(x) = f(x)e^{-i\omega (x\pm x_n)} \ \\ \ u(x) = f(x)e^{-i\omega x} $$
Clearly, $$ u_n \to u $$

Now, $$\ u\ is\ L^1,\ so\ is\ each\ u_n$$

We also have $$\left |u_n \right | \leq \left | f \right |\ and\ f\ is\ L^1$$
Now use DCT to get:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}|u_n-u| \to 0\ as \ n \to \infty $$

Comment: You misunderstood the question. What you are showing in part I is that the Fourier transform is a continuous map from $L^1$ to $L^\infty$. The question was about the uniform continuity of the function $\hat{f}(\xi)$ as a function of $\xi$. The map $\xi \mapsto \hat{f}(\xi)$ is not linear in general. In part II you actually give a correct proof, but this is a duplicate of previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that for real $x,y \in \mathbb R$,
$$|e^{ix}-e^{iy}|\leq |x-y| \wedge 2.$$
Then
$$|\hat f (\xi +h )-\hat f (\xi)| \leq  \int |f(x)| (|2\pi x h|\wedge 2) \mathrm dx, $$ so we have a bound not depending on $\xi$, which goes to zero as $|h| \to \infty$ by the dominated convergence theorem.