# How to prove $\hat f$ is uniformly continuous in $R^n$?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let the Fourier transform be defined by $\hat f(\xi)=\int_{R^n}f(x)e^{-ix\xi}dx$.

Suppose $f\in L^1(R^n)$. How to prove $\hat f$ is uniformly continuous in $R^n$?

Comment: You should check out the related posts

Comment: @Timkinsella Thanks! I found this post is similar. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68642/fourier-transform-is-uniformly-continuous?rq=1