# Unif. continuity of Laplace transform

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, laplace-transform, uniform-continuity

If I have a positive random variable $X$, how  can I show that its Laplace transform $$L_X(t)=E[e^{-tX}] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-tx}f(x)dx, \quad t>0$$  where $f(x)$ is the density of the r.v. $X$,  is **uniformly continuous** ?

I just know the $\epsilon$ - $\delta$ definition of uniform continuity.

I would start with $$|L(t+h) - L(t)|=||\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_X(x) e^{-tx} \bigl( e^{-hx} - 1 \bigr)dx|| \leq \int_\mathbb{R}|| f_X(x)|| e^{-tx}  |e^{-hx} - 1 |dx$$ but then I don't know how to go on.

Actually, I wanted to use the same trick used for the fact that the Fourier transform is *uniformly continuous* as explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68642/fourier-transform-is-uniformly-continuous), but I get stuck.

Comment: How is $E$ defined?

Comment: It's the expected value , editing

Comment: How is it defined as an integral?

Comment: Just edited my question. It's the usual laplace transform, where $f$ is the density function of a random variable

Comment: You seem to have started your proof in a way that's different to the answer for the Fourier transform.

Comment: Yes, the fact is that the complex exponential has modulus 1 and somehow simplifies the proof there

Comment: Do you follow the proof that was given there? Do you know what the DCT is?

Comment: Yes I'm looking at that proof, and yes, I know DCT

Comment: But you haven't started the proof in the same way.

Comment: You're right! :) Indeed I am editing it

Comment: Just edited @OliverJones

Comment: What did the answer give as the next step?

Comment: It uses the fact that the modulus of the exponential is one, but here I can't use it, that's why I get stuck

Comment: No, he makes a claim about a limit.

Comment: Yes, he takes $h$ to $0$, IF I could do that, then the claim follows. To be able to do that, I need to use DCT,

Comment: I'm editing my quesiton

Comment: So you really didn't understand the proof then.

Comment: @OliverJones are you looking to "JavaMan" answer, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $t_n \to t$ then $Ee^{-t_nX} \to Ee^{-tX}$ by DCT, so $L_X$ is continuous. Also $L_X(t) \to 0$ as $ t\to \infty$ by DCT and any continuous function on $[0,\infty)$ which vanishes at $\infty$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Thanks @Kavi Rama Murthy, but I am not allowed to use the tool you had in your answer. I need some explicit computation as the one I tried to do above

Comment: By the way, the DCT applies because for $t>0$ I have $e^{-t X(\omega)}| \leq 1 $ since $X(\omega) \leq 0$ for every $\omega \in \Omega$, right?

Comment: @andereBen Yes. DCT applies because $0 <e^{-tX} \leq 1$.